# Where to find list of binaries available in Heroku build environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Title says it all.

If I understand correctly, the Heroku VM environment provides some built-in binaries and then additional ones can be provided in a custom build pak.

Trial (by building a little test app) and error (by having the build fail) is the only way forward so far. Surely there's a better way.

I have read the Heroku docs and looked in obvious places in the [Ruby build pak source](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby). No list.

My immediate aim is to determine if a Rails app that requires GD2 graphics (the `gd2-ruby` gem) will build without a custom build pak. But the general question of binaries availability comes up again and again.

Comment: You could just do `heroku run bash`, and get a shell in a plain dyno. Then list all rpms installed.

Comment: Thanks  @NitzanShaked very much.  I'm not an Ubuntu wizard.  Is `dpkg --list` the right command?  Do you know by chance if the default Ruby buildpak has any binaries in it?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections`, as for example here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages, or here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/. I don't know the ruby buildpack at all, but I am pretty sure it does not contain gd.

Comment: @NitzanShaked Many thanks. If you are celebrating holidays right now, have happy ones.

Comment: :) That's the best kind of StackOverflow response there is.

Comment: @NitzanShaked The `dpkg --get-selections` works great. If you write this as a proper answer, I will select it.  `libgd2-noxpm` was listed, so my question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `heroku run bash`, and get a shell in a plain dyno. Then list all rpms installed by invoking `dpkg --get-selections`, as for example here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages or here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/